# I've created a 3D engine and the result looks very strange

Tags: java, object, 3d

So yeah, as stated above, i've build a 3D Engine and i tried to import a Utah teapod. For self made objects (like a box or so) it worked well, but when i tried the teapod the following happens:

[image]

It looks like at least one of the points of each triangle is off and these cross-sections form for some reason. I used a normal obj. file (except i deleted the v up front), this is only about the assignment of points to each triangle.

This is the code i used:

```
public void defineShapes() { 
        //InputStream is = getFileFromResourceAsStream("obj.txt");
        
        tet = new Tetrahedron();
        
        Scanner s;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new File("res/obj.txt"));
            MyTriangle[] array = new MyTriangle[(int) (1200)];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                String z1 = s.nextLine();
                String z2 = s.nextLine();
                String z3 = s.nextLine();
                
                array[i] = convert(z1, z2, z3);
            }
            tet.polygons = array;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { }
        
        for(int i = 1; i < tet.polygons.length; i++) {
            tet.polygons[i-1].color = new Color((i*255)/tet.polygons.length, (i*255)/tet.polygons.length, (i*255)/tet.polygons.length);
        }
    }
    
    public MyTriangle convert (String t1, String t2, String t3) {
        String[] temp1 = t3.split(" ", 3);
        String[] temp2 = t2.split(" ", 3);
        String[] temp3 = t1.split(" ", 3);
        
        double a1 = Double.parseDouble(temp1[0]);
        double a2 = Double.parseDouble(temp1[1]);
        double a3 = Double.parseDouble(temp1[2]);
        double b1 = Double.parseDouble(temp2[0]);
        double b2 = Double.parseDouble(temp2[1]);
        double b3 = Double.parseDouble(temp2[2]);
        double c1 = Double.parseDouble(temp3[0]);
        double c2 = Double.parseDouble(temp3[1]);
        double c3 = Double.parseDouble(temp3[2]);
        
        
        return new MyTriangle(this, new MyPoint[] {new MyPoint(a1, a2, a3), new MyPoint(b1, b2, b3), new MyPoint(c1, c2, c3)});
    }
```

I really hope one of you has had this problem before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are creating a Tetrahedron for each triangle and giving only 3 vertex...

Comment: You are looping from `i-1` to `last-1` but last index `< length` is `length-1` so `last = length - 2`

Comment: @maborg I designed it that way because i only had one Tetrahedron to display, i'll change that to a list of vertices, which are then primitiveAssebled to triangles in the future, this is only for test.

Comment: @IQbrod That last loop is only for assigning colors though. I didn't want A Black triangle because my Background is black. I can change that, but that doesnt change the way the points are asigned to the triangles. There should be no triangles going from one side of the pod to the other, they should only cover the surface, but for some reason, no matter what i do, they don't